# How to retrieve value from a list and update in a matrix using excel

Tags: excel, matrix

I developed a vegetation model in excel and need to add a grazing function.

I have several matrix which do all the calculations for the vegetation components, and now I have a list of steps (random cells visited, 750 out of 2500) and how much biomass was taken from that specific cell.

I need to update each cell value from that list into matrix format again, to calculate the remaining biomass. I've tried several combinations of "index" and "match" and lookups, but could not make it work.

I even numbered all 2500 cells for making it more simple, instead of using row and column reference. Any clue?? (would be the oposit of retrieving a value from a matrix using function Index)

Comment: I'm thinking a VBA macro might work for you. Do you have row and column values for the random cells visited? Do you want to update the original matrix or write to a new matrix?

Comment: @dev1998, thanks for the answer. I am not very familiar with the VBA coding itself. I do have all info for the visited cells, both row and column and also a specific number (I numbered all 2500 cells). The value probably should go into a new matrix, so I can use that (the harvested forage) to subtract from the original (available forage). I am using macros to calculate each time step of the model. I tried writing the cells name (Column + row) as a text, and use the vlookup to update, but did not succeed.

Comment: I've posted an answer. You may have do some adjusting to make it fit what you have. Let me know if your not sure how to get the VBA code loaded into your workbook.

Comment: Thanks!! I am not sure yet but I will get it done, don't worry. That should be the easiest part. I am getting quite a big model, may have to switch to R later, but as I am not very familiar with R, for the model development I am using excel. Later on, with more time, I may change to another program (or reduce the size of the excel one, say 10x10 instead of 50x50). Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something that I think will work for you. I created 3 worksheets. They are named VegMatrix, VisitedCells, and VegMatrixNew.

VegMatrix is the starting matrix and I assumed it was a 50 x 50 with the first data cell in A1. Here is a partial picture:

[image: VegMatrix]

The next sheet is CellsVisited. It has the rows, cols and the amout of vegetation removed from the cell.

[image: CellsVisited]

The third sheet is named VegMatrixNew.  This is what the original matrix will look like after the removal occurs.

[image: VegMatrixNew]

This is done using these VBA macros: They will copy the starting VegMatrix data over to the VegMatrixNew sheet. Then it will loop through the rows in the CellsVisited sheet and get the row, column and amount removed for each cell. The amount removed is subtracted from corresponding cell in VegMatrixNew.

```
Sub VegRemove()

    Dim Wbk As Workbook

    Set Wbk = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim vegRemoved As Integer

    Dim numRows As Integer
    CopySheet

    Worksheets("VisitedCells").Activate
    numRows = Wbk.Worksheets("VisitedCells").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count


    For x = 2 To numRows + 1 'start at 2 because of header.

        row = Worksheets("VisitedCells").Cells(x, 1).Value
        col = Worksheets("VisitedCells").Cells(x, 2).Value
        vegRemoved = Worksheets("VisitedCells").Cells(x, 3).Value

        Worksheets("VegMatrixNew").Cells(row, col).Value = Worksheets("VegMatrix").Cells(row, col).Value - vegRemoved

    Next x

End Sub
Sub CopySheet()

    Sheets("VegMatrix").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("VegMatrixNew").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a little easier way to do that:

I built a matrix with cell references (which correspond to the original vegetation matrix)

[Harvested and corresponding reference table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XByPj.jpg)

Then I randomly generated the amount harvested from each cell. The "Reference" uses "index" function to search for the values of X (row) and Y  (column) and gives the "cell name" for those specific coordinates.

[Reference matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zhJa.jpg)

On another matrix, I have a if.error function followed by a value lookup

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Reference matrix","Reference --> Amount harvested",2,FALSE),0)

Now I can use this lates table to subtract from the original vegetation matrix.

(sorry I could not make this more clear but SO is keeping me from embeding tables and from posting more than two picture links).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the last table that I could not post before:

[Updated harvested matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM9oH.jpg)

The "IFERROR" places "0" where there is no information from the harvested list (cells not harvested)